# EF Effort Testing Library Throws 'TargetInvocationException'

Tags: entity-framework, csv

When trying to create an ObjectContext using the CreateTransient factory with a loader, I'm consistently getting an error:

> "TargetInvocationException was unhandled by user code"

with an inner exception of:

> "The specified named connection is either not found in the
>   configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider,
>   or not valid"

```
var loader = new CsvDataLoader(@"C:\MyProject\MyProject.Tests\Data\Info.csv");

using (var context = ObjectContextFactory.CreateTransient<MyEntities>(loader))
{
    ...
}
```

I can create a standard context just fine, and I can create a Transient ObjectContext without a loader, but I can not load a csv file. The csv was generated by the Effort export tool.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the exact error!. I have resolved it by copying the connection string for EF model to Test project's app.Config. Because this is where my "Effort" is being created. Hope this helps.